# fileschanged installation problem

Tags: linux, package-management

I can't install fileschanged anymore. when I tried to sudo apt install fileschanged
I got this error `E: Unable to locate package fileschanged`

And when trying to download from source and build I get this error `checking for FAMOpen in -lfam... no To build this software, you must install the FAM development package`

I need this because I have to monitor a shared folder on a VM Linux guest which is on Windows host. inotify won't do

Comment: The package seems to be available [in Debian buster (oldstable)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/fileschanged).  What are you running?  Did you try installing the FAM development package?